# Which button of JSpinner has been pressed?

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to know , from inside a ChangeListener receiving a ChangeEvent from a JSpinner,
which button (increment/decrement) has been pressed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer : No there's no way to know which button was pressed

Long answer : depending on your model and your change listener, if you do a comparison between the new value and the previous value, it is possible to know if the user went forward or backward.

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the object firing the event. Perhaps save the value prior to the event and determine whether it went up or down during the event.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the actual value to the previous one. Here is how:

```
ChangeEvent ce = ...
((JSpinner)ce.getSource()).getPreviousValue();
```

Comment: I think this will just return the next value down from the current value, not the value that was previously selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the new value against the old value by storing the old value:

```
int currentValue = spinner.getValue();
spinner.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent e) {
        int value = spinner.getValue();
        if(value > currentValue) {
            // up was pressed
        } else if(value < currentValue) {
            // down was pressed
        }
        currentValue = value;
    }
});
```

Comment: yes , i understand that, but what i would like to do is use the JSpinner in such a way that the current value holds the step size, and incrementing/decrementing buttons are used to modify another field in my gui according to the step. So next and previous values should always remains the same, except if i manually modify the step value displayed . I don't know if my explanation is clear enough. Thanks anyway for your solution

Comment: @Overbose - in that case, maybe you want to have your other value listen to the `SpinnerModel`?  That seems like it might be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

JSpinner is a composite component, it's possible to add mouseListeners to the components it contains.  You'd have to experiment a bit to work out how to distinguish the buttons from one another and from the text field.  One quick and dirty way would be to check their coordinates.

I'm not sure if you want to iterate over the components contained by the JSpinner itself, or those contained by the container returned by `JSpinner.getEditor()`, so try both.