# Java - How can i get the index of a JSpinner selected item?

Tags: java, swing, duplicates, jspinner

I have a JSpinner control that has random values. The values can be duplicates. For example :

> { 1, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5, 9, 6, 7, 3, 2, 9 }

If the user has selected the value 9, then how can i differentiate it from the other 9s in the JSpinner, because my program will make some calculations depending on the index of the selected 9.

**My solution is to get the index of the selected item in the JSpinner to know which one is this. Is it possible ?**

Comment: @cesarluis That answer will not work. In this example if the value is 9 then the index returned will always be 2 even if index 7 or index 11 is selected.

Comment: Either use a JList instead or you will have get the `SpinerModel` and keep calling `getNextValue` and compare the results to the source list until you figure out where you are.

Comment: @markbernard .. You're right. The suggested solution for cesarluis will always return the index of the first 9. I thought about using getNextValue & getPreviousValue, but it will be so complicated. I hope there is an easier way.

Comment: @Brad sorry i was wrong i did not pay enough attention.Now  Im thinking in count up and down clicks/change listeners. Maybe this approach is useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184639/which-button-of-jspinner-has-been-pressed. The problem is duplicates very close so you can make a close-values buffer or control your combinations.

Comment: I would use a JComboBox, then you just use the getSelectedIndex() method.  `I thought about using getNextValue & getPreviousValue,` - what if the user doesn't use the arrow keys and instead types in a value?

Answer (score 0):

jspiner.getValue() will give you the value of the selected item, you can do whatever with it, why do you need to know it's index? form the Java doc for SpinnerModel

> The model doesn't support indexed random access to sequence elements. Only three sequence values are accessible at a time: current, next and previous.

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error i found the best solution for my case, and i am sharing it here just in case anyone had the same scenario. I have added spaces before each duplicated numbers in the spinner to know which one is this and make each value  in the spinner unique, so the first 9 will be {space + 9}, the second 9 will be {2 spaces + 9}, and the third 9 will be {3 spaces + 9}.

Adding spaces in the spinner will not be of any problem to the user, and i think i might make the spinner editor not editable so if the user tries to enter the values manually he won't mess up things.